# Fill column with nan if sum of multiple columns is 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fill

**Task**

I have a `df` where I do some ratios that are groupby `date` and `id`. I want to fill column `c` with `NaN` if the sum of `a` and `b` is 0. Any help would be awesome!!

**df**

```
      date      id   a    b   c
0   2001-09-06  1    3    1   1
1   2001-09-07  1    3    1   1
2   2001-09-08  1    4    0   1
3   2001-09-09  2    6    0   1
4   2001-09-10  2    0    0   2
5   2001-09-11  1    0    0   2
6   2001-09-12  2    1    1   2
7   2001-09-13  2    0    0   2
8   2001-09-14  1    0    0   2
```

Comment: does `df['c'].mask((df['a']+df['b']).eq(0))` what you are looking for? I'm not sure I get where the groupby comes in there

Comment: Thanks @Ben.T, works great. Say if the sum in `a` and `b` is less than or equal to 0, how would this be represented ?

Comment: instead of `eq` you can use `le` (standing for less than or equal) :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df['new_c'] = df.c.where(df[['a','b']].sum(1).ne(0))


Out[75]:
         date  id  a  b  c  new_c
0  2001-09-06   1  3  1  1    1.0
1  2001-09-07   1  3  1  1    1.0
2  2001-09-08   1  4  0  1    1.0
3  2001-09-09   2  6  0  1    1.0
4  2001-09-10   2  0  0  2    NaN
5  2001-09-11   1  0  0  2    NaN
6  2001-09-12   2  1  1  2    2.0
7  2001-09-13   2  0  0  2    NaN
8  2001-09-14   1  0  0  2    NaN
```

Comment: @Ben.T: yeah, same thing. Just different flavor :)

Comment: Thanks @Andy L., works great. Say if the sum in `a` and `b` is less than or equal to 0, how would this be represented ?

Comment: @oceanbeach96:  instead of `ne(0)`, use `gt(0)`

Answer (score 1):

It is better to build a new dataframe with same shape , and then do the following :

```
i = 0
for line in df :
    new_df[i]['date'] = line['date']
    new_df[i]['a'] = line['a']
    new_df[i]['b'] = line['b']
    if line['a'] + line['b'] == 0 :
       new_df[i]['c'] = Nan
i += 1
```

Comment: I have to create approx 200 different ratios. Is there a better option then having to do this each time? I don't think looping over each row is efficient aswell!

Comment: @oceanbeach96 i dont really have an idea , but the reason to create a new df is to avoid immutability